# How to read NumberFormatException error message?

Tags: java, swing, debugging, exception, stack-trace

**[NOTE]** Add to the answer below for other good tips for reading the stack trace

I am getting an error in a program that I am making and I don't know how to fix it.

The user has to choose options from messageboxes, and I have to use the users input to calculate the tuition they will have and their discount.

### If I run it!

```
 run: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
                at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
                at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:468)
                at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:497)
                at cabrera.Main.main(Main.java:26)
        Java Result: 1
        BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

### Code

```
package cabrera;

/**
 *
 * @author Owner
 */
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String tuition1 = "", scholar1 = "";
        int tuition = 0, scholar = 0;
        double discount = 0.0;

        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Your Tuition" + tuition1);
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose A Scholar Discount:" + "\n• 1 = 80% " + "\n• 2 = 50%" + "\n• 3 = 25%" + "\n• 4 = No Discount !" + scholar1);

        tuition = Integer.parseInt(tuition1);
        scholar = Integer.parseInt(scholar1);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Total Tuition is: " + tuition);

        // If-elseif-else statements based on scholar variable

    }
}
```

**How do I fix this error message?**

### More Info

I recently came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100505/else-if-statement-multiple-input-message-dialog-boxes-pr) that was badly executed. Bad title, bad code, bad question (actually not question, but it could be assumed after some thought). It was from a new SO user.

I wanted to help out and looked at the code for a while. So I edited the post; fixed the code layout, simplified the code, ask the question the OP wanted to ask, etc.... That question is now above; however, the question was put on hold, and I read that questions can take a long time to get off of `On Hold`. You need something like 5 votes to reopen after it is put on hold. Something I don't see that will happen given that it has been a while since the question was first asked.

I had the answer complete and don't want to waste a good answer

Comment: i know its answered but just adding --- String tuition1 = "0", scholar1 = "0";

Comment: That alone would not actually fix the issue! OP does not actually update `tuition1` and `scholar1`, so the `if-elseif-else` clauses at the bottom will only go to the `if (scholar1 == "0")` clause. But the OP might then be wondering why the first messagebox always says `Input Your Tuition0` rather than just `Input Your Tuition`

Comment: **Yes i completely agree with your solution** , and your answer is a good practice and well written , but when i was **new to programming** , setting to 0 was a beginners way to work . so just added up a comment

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**OK, lets look at how to find the issue first!**

```
(3) run: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
               at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
               at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:468)
(2)            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:497)
(1)            at cabrera.Main.main(Main.java:26)
    Java Result: 1
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

**Look at...**

- `(1)`, here you can see in `Main.java` you have an issue on `line 26`
- `(2)`, here you can see more information on the issue. In fact you know you have an issue with Integer.parseInt.

  - You Don't have to worry about looking at this code, because you don't have a class called `Integer` with method `parseInt` in the package `java.lang`
  - You just know there is an issue here, and it deals with `Integer.parseInt` which you do call in your `Main.java` code!
  - **So we located a possible area to check for the error!**

    ```
    tuition = Integer.parseInt(tuition1);    
    scholar = Integer.parseInt(scholar1);
    ```
- `(3)`, here we can see that a `NumberFormatException` was throw because you gave it (the `Integer.parseInt` that is) an input of `""` (an empty string)

---

### So How do you fix it?

1. First, you have to look at the input of `Integer.parseInt`

   - You can see you pass in `tuition1` and `scholar1`
2. Look to see where those 2 variable are changed / created.

   - You can see the last thing you did was create those two variables and assigned them the empty string (`""`)
   - **There is the problem!!**
3. So you need to assign them a value from the user. That will be done via the `showInputDialog(...)`.

   - the `showInputDialog(...)` **returns a value that you can use!** [See here!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int))
   - All you have to do is...

     ```
     tuition1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Your Tuition");     
     scholar1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose A Scholar Discount: 1... 2... 3... 4...")
     ```
   - **Take note that `tuition1` and `scholar1` should NOT be placed inside of the dialog box when you want to assign them values from the user**. You need to have the user input some text into the dialog box, and that value will be returned when you press the OK button. So you have to assign that return value to `tuition1` and `scholar1`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception because user is free to enter an input which is not a number. `Integer.parseInt(String s)` will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the argument passed to this method is not a valid number. You can restrict the user to input only numbers by the use of regular expressions. The code is below:

```
String tuition1="";     
int tuition = 0;
boolean numFound =false;
try{
    while(!numFound){
        tuition1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Your Tuition:");
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z,a-z,&%$#@!()*^]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(tuition1);
        if (m.find()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter only numbers");
        }
        else{       
            tuition = Integer.parseInt(tuition1);       
            numFound = true;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will show a message to user "Please enter only numbers", if he tries to enter something that cannot be converted to integer.

Comment: While that is a possible issue, that was actually not way the `NumberFormatException was thrown`! It would have been thrown regardless of what was entered into the Messagebox. Take a look at the code, `tuition1` and `scholar1` was never updated!

Comment: This is an answer to another question, but it does show one way of avoiding non-number entries, but it fails in 2 ways. `1` it is too advanced for the user. `2` there is no loop to reenter in the value for `tuition1`.

Comment: Edited my answer to include the loop to reenter the value. Using exception handling mechanism to reenter the loop is not a good idea. this can be simply accomplished with a `boolean` variable.